# unable to loadrequest for webview from another viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I am implementing FB kind of functionality where I

1. populate a list of menu from database on left side.
2. clicking any of menu loads a related web page inside webview.

Both Menu's and Webview are in different viewcontroller

When menu gets clicked, I send  notification message to first viewcontroller and inside notification message I write code to loadRequest.

However this is not working. I am able to loadRequest successfully from first Viewcontroller.however it is not possible to do from another viewcontroller.

here is my code:

**ViewController 1:**

in ViewLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter *note = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[note addObserver:self selector:@selector(eventDidFire:) name:@"ILikeTurtlesEvent" object:nil];

    - (void) eventDidFire:(NSNotification *)note {
            web.delegate=self;
        [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
     }
```

in **ViewController 2:**

```
NSNotificationCenter *note = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[note postNotificationName:@"ILikeTurtlesEvent" object:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the another option for what you are trying to do:

```
viewcontroller1.h:
-(void)clickmenu:(id)sender;

viewcontroller1.m:
-(void)clickmenu:(id)sender
{
  viewcontroller2 *obj = [[viewcontroller2 alloc] initWithNibName: @"viewcontroller2" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
[obj Loadwebview:[NSURL urlwithstring:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}


ViewController2.h:
-(void)Loadwebview:(NSURL *)url;
viewcontroller2.m:
-(void)Loadwebview:(NSURL *)url
{
      web.delegate=self;
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: Here at your code clickmenu needs to b invoked for all process to execute. But this is not scenario for my problem..request is initiated from Viewcontroller2 not viewcontroller1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution i removed the line:

web.delegate=self; 
and code worked!! weird !! but true . Here is my working code:

```
- (void) eventDidFire:(NSNotification *)note {
  // web.delegate=self;
 [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.11.77:5200/test/test.html"]]];

}
```

Hope it helps others!!!  ":)